# postgres subquery w/ derived column

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query won't work, but it should be clear what I'm trying to do: split the value of 't' on space and use the last element in that array in the subquery (as it will match tl). Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

```
SELECT t, y, "type",
regexp_split_to_array(t, ' ') as t_array, sum(dr), (

select uz from f.tfa where tl = t_array[-1]

)
as uz,
sc
FROM padres.yd_fld
WHERE y = 2010 AND pos <> 0
GROUP BY t, y, "type", sc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can you a negative index to reference an array element in postgresql (documentation) ?

```
test=# select t from 
      (select regexp_split_to_array('hi man bye', ' ') as t) as x;       
--------------
 {hi,man,bye}
(1 row)

test=# select t[1] from 
      (select regexp_split_to_array('hi man bye', ' ') as t) as x;
 t
----
 hi
(1 row)

test=# select t[-1] from 
      (select regexp_split_to_array('hi man bye', ' ') as t) as x;
 t
---

(1 row)
```

I find strange that it doesn't give an error, though...

The correct way would be:

```
test=# select t[array_length(t,1)] from 
  (select regexp_split_to_array('hi man bye', ' ') as t) as x;
  t
-----
 bye
```

Also, see here:

[Getting the last word from a Postgres string, declaratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949881/getting-the-last-element-of-a-postgres-array-declaratively/2950441#2950441)

Comment: "Also, null is returned if a subscript is outside the array bounds (this case does not raise an error)." (an [excerpt](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) from the docs).

Comment: +1 I'd missed that. I wondered about negative indexes, which at first thought would be inherently invalid. But they are not, as postgresql allows arbitrary lower indexes in the array declaration. And I see that Postgresql doesnt gives error even when the dimensions are incompatible.